# Javascript reserved keywords int, long, float, etc

Tags: javascript

What do these reserved type words do in current javascript? Will they actually create a variable that adheres only to a certain type? If not, could I at least declare a normal variable using one instead of `var` just for readability? Could I use one to specify a function should return a certain type? I like the clarity that gives my code when I write in C, so even if this will just create a regular javascript variable...

```
float myFloat = 0.0;
```

..I would actually like to write it this way. Or if I could write...

```
float function() {
  float myFloat = 4.6;
  return myFloat;
}
```

that would be nifty too. I know these words are reserved for "possible" future use, so if they work like this, wouldn't it just be kind of good practice to do this for future-proofing?

Comment: you can write "float: myFloat = 0.0;" if it makes you happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as of ECMAScript 5 these keyword are not reserved for future use anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Now assuming that they were still reserved keywords, declaring `float myFloat = 0.0` still wouldn't work because the JavaScript engine expects variable declaration to be of the form `var  myFloat = 0.0` or simply `myFloat = 0.0`.

Using these keywords would result in a Syntax Error. Reserved words do not mean "use these keywords as you'd do in other languages, we'll implement the feature later". It means that they are not part of the language right now and you can't use them.